# Set global text color in Vuetify

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, vuetify.js

I've setup a Vuetify app with sass globals, changing the default font style. However, I'm having trouble finding the setting for font/text color. There is a text-color property under $material-light and $material-dark variables that I believe is the correct attribute to set, but haven't managed to get it to work.

in /sass/variables.sass

```
$material-light: map-deep-merge(( 'text-color': #554946 ), $material-light)
```

This results in a invalid css property 'text-color' error. Any idea what the correct way to change this property is?

Answer (score 0):

For Vuetify 2.6.x

Import the variables on top of your `variables.scss` file:

```
@import '~vuetify/src/styles/settings/_index.sass';
```

Then add the overrides

```
$material-light: map-deep-merge(
  $material-light,
  (
    'text': (
      'primary': <your color> // This is the text value that sets the global color
    )
  )
);
```

The full variable definition is here: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/vuetify/#sass-material-light

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way would be to simply set the font-family on `body`. If you are using webpack and importing the Vuetify stylus entry, `main.styl`, you can simply overwrite the `$font-family` variable with whatever font you want.

Comment: To clarify, setting the font family isn't an issue. I have done that successfully with the $body-font-family in variables.sass. Only the color is an issue, as even with setting a global color through the body, the individual vuetify components will override it back to black.